# Ruby - use a Constant for 'case" statements conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Ruby case statement that looks like:

```
case ruby_variable
when "instagram"
  # do this
when "twitter"
  # do that
  # and so on...
else
  "theres an error"
end
```

I also have a constant with all the social network names (this list willl vary in time):

```
NETWORKS_LIST = 
[   "instagram",
        "twitter",
        "pinterest",
        .......
    ]
```

I would like to change this so that the conditon values, that is to say "pinterest", "twitter" and others, *populate automatically* into my case statement (but keep the last line else "error").

Something like a loop:

```
case ruby_variable
when NETWORKS_LIST[0]
  do this
when NETWORKS_LIST[1]
  do that
and so on...
else
  "theres an error"
end
```

I'm not sure how to manage this.

Comment: Can you not use a hash?

Comment: a `constant` that will `vary in time`?

Comment: You should give a real example instead of `do this` , `do that` .. that would help to figure out whether a Hash can be used here or not.

Comment: I agree with @sagarpandya82 if you want this type of functionality and depending on what "do this" and "do that" are a Hash of network => Proc might work well for you e.g. `NETWORK_LIST = {"instagram" => Proc.new { do this }}`. then you could call with `NETWORK_LIST[ruby_variable].try(:call) || "there's an error"`

Comment: Did you check the scope of Constant you have decide?

Comment: @Fallenhero More like "the structure will change and evolve over time" which is natural in any non-trivial application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you use a structure like an Array to look up things and test validity, a Hash to define mappings, or a case to branch execution. It's highly unusual when more than one of these is involved at the same level of your solution, that is they're used in a way that's tightly inter-linked.

I think there's a few things that are confused here. Constants of this sort are best used for look-ups, like testing if your parameters are valid:

```
NETWORKS_LIST.include?(params[:network])
```

If you want to re-use values in that list elsewhere the Ruby convention is to prefer Symbols over Strings:

```
NETWORKS_LIST = [
  :instagram,
  :pinterest,
  :weratedogs
]
```

Then in your `case` statement:

```
case params[:network]
when :instagram
  make_instagram_post!
when :pinterest
  make_pin!
when :weratedogs
  bark_incessantly!
else
  raise "Not a valid network."
end
```

You maintain these two structures independently *because* the `case` statement has additional code in it that's not encapsulated in the original structure. Now you can always merge the two:

```
NETWORKS = Hash.new(-> {
  raise "Not a valid network."
}).merge(
  instagram: -> {
    make_instagram_post!
  },
  pinterest: -> {
    make_pin!
  },
  weratedogs: -> {
    bark_incessantly!
  }
)
```

This has a default value that's a Proc which raises an error, so you can just call it like this:

```
NETWORKS[params[:network].to_sym].call
```

That will either do whatever's expected or error out provided `params[:network]` is populated.

You can evolve this further into a little Ruby DSL if you want.

Comment: thanks yes some things were not clear to me, now is better

Comment: I was using string vs symbol because the "instagram", "twitter" is choosen/selected by users on active admin. they type their choice so it becomes a string and then i say if he chose "instagram" then do this....

Comment: @Mathieu a string can be symbolized very easily using `to_sym` or `intern`.

Comment: @Mathieu As @engineersmnky says, `"example".to_sym` is `:example`, just as `:example.to_s` is `"example"`, so these are largely interchangeable for any given String value, even an empty string. The only thing to note is `nil` cannot be converted to a Symbol.